# SQL Paginate When Sorting By Two Keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

With a message archive application, I want to paginate through a table of message subjects efficiently. This is easy enough if I sort just by date. I can remember the first and last dates shown on the page and then query for a set of messages greater or less than those. But the application allows some messages to be pinned; they should always appear before other messages, regardless of whether the messages are sorted by ascending or descending date. A message is pinned if a bool is togged true on the record.

What's the best way to efficiently page through this? Assume the table is very large, and messages can be added and deleted at will. We're using Postgres if that makes a difference.

EDIT: I know how to ORDER BY to get what I want. The question is how best to paginate through the results (ie not by using OFFSET).

Comment: `order by boolean_column, date`

Comment: What does "pinned" even mean?  Does it mean that a given message will always appear in the same position?  Can you give us an example?

Comment: If a message is pinned, it means it appears first when sorting the messages.

Comment: Should these "pinned" messages appear on every page, or it is possible to paginate to where there are no more of these "pinned" messages? Also, with multiple pinned messages, their order should be the same as the "not-pinned" messages (f.ex. date asc/desc)?

Comment: `select...where pinned and date between`?.. changing the range will always take pinned as well

Comment: Also, I hope you search for pagination, which does not use LIMIT **and** OFFSET by *ie not by using LIMIT/OFFSET*. Because `LIMIT` will be necessary for paginating anyway.

Comment: The pinned messages should only appear on the first page. And yes, I will always need to use LIMIT. I will fix the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the messages with an `ORDER BY` clause and get the first 50 entries like that:

```
ORDER BY NOT pinned, create_timestamp LIMIT 50
```

Remember the last `(NOT pinned, create_timestamp)` combination.

To retrieve the next page, use

```
WHERE (NOT pinned, create_timestamp) > (last_notpinned, last_createts)
ORDER BY NOT pinned, create_timestamp LIMIT 50
```

and so on for the following pages.

You'll need an index like

```
CREATE INDEX ON tablename ((NOT pinned), create_timestamp);
```

to make all this efficient.

Comment: Just a note for people using Postgres. When using an operator like NOT when creating an index, you need to surround it with parentheses, like: `CREATE INDEX ON tablename ((NOT pinned), create_timestamp);`

Comment: Thanks, I have added them.